# How do I add default parameters to functions when using type hinting?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

If I have a function like this:

```
def foo(name, opts={}):
  pass
```

And I want to add type hints to the parameters, how do I do it? The way I assumed gives me a syntax error:

```
def foo(name: str, opts={}: dict) -> str:
  pass
```

The following doesn't throw a syntax error but it doesn't seem like the intuitive way to handle this case:

```
def foo(name: str, opts: dict={}) -> str:
  pass
```

I can't find anything in the [`typing` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) or on a Google search.

Edit: I didn't know how default arguments worked in Python, but for the sake of this question, I will keep the examples above. In general it's much better to do the following:

```
def foo(name: str, opts: dict=None) -> str:
  if not opts:
    opts={}
  pass
```

Comment: The last function is the correct way. It's the same way `scala` language does it too.

Comment: you have a mutable default type - that will lead to problems

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ Not unless you're using it for, e.g. memoization. :P

Answer (score 723, accepted):

Your second way is correct.

```
def foo(opts: dict = {}):
    pass

print(foo.__annotations__)
```

this outputs

```
{'opts': <class 'dict'>}
```

It's true that's it's not listed in [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/), but type hints are an application of function annotations, which are documented in PEP 3107. [The syntax section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/#syntax) makes it clear that keyword arguments works with function annotations in this way.

I strongly advise against using mutable keyword arguments. More information [here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments).

Comment: See http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/#syntax. Type hinting is just an application of function annotations.

Comment: @chepner true. didn't know that PEP 3107 had something about keyword arguments.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about the mutable default arguments in Python... especially coming from Javascript/Ruby where default arguments work differently. Not gonna rehash what's already been said ad nauseum around SO about it, I'm just glad I found out about this before it bit me. Thanks!

Comment: I was always advised to use None rather than a mutable type like {} or [] or a default object as mutations to that object without a deep-copy will persist between iterations.

Comment: define enough functions with mutable keyword arguments and it is only a matter of time before you find yourself looking back on a 4 hour debugging session questioning your life choices

Comment: Shouldn't there be no whitespace around the `=` in `dict = {}` like it is convention for non-type-hinted keyword arguments?

Comment: @actual_panda Not according to [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#other-recommendations:~:text=when%20combining%20an%20argument%20annotation%20with%20a%20default%20value%2C%20however%2C%20do%20use%20spaces%20around%20the%20%3D%20sign%3A), at least.

Comment: UPDATE: Since python v3.10, you can use:
``def foo(arg: dict | None = None) -> dict | None:``

See: https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/typing.html#typing.Union

Answer (score 114):

If you're using [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) (introduced in Python 3.5) you can use `typing.Optional`, where `Optional[X]` is equivalent to `Union[X, None]`. It is used to signal that the explicit value of `None` is allowed . From [typing.Optional](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional):

```
def foo(arg: Optional[int] = None) -> None:
    ...
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be no whitespace around the `=` in `Optional[int] = None` like it is convention for non-type-hinted keyword arguments?

Comment: @actual_panda the answer is correct. the style is different when there are type hints. there are examples in [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)

Comment: @actual_panda Not according to [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#other-recommendations:~:text=when%20combining,%2E%2E%2E,-compound). Also, if you're going to post a comment twice on the same page, you should consider asking it as its own question. As noted in the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment#:~:text=when%20shouldn%27t,the%20following%3A&text=secondary%20discussion,chat%20instead%3B) for the `comment everywhere` privilege, “Comments are not recommended for … Secondary discussion”

Comment: or `def foo(arg: int | None = None) -> None:` in the newer syntax

Answer (score 41):

I recently saw this one-liner:

```
def foo(name: str, opts: dict=None) -> str:
    if opts is None:
        opts = {}
    pass  # ...
```

Comment: Hi @Kirkalicious, thanks for your answer. Could you explain how it works?

Comment: The empty dict passed as a default parameter is the same dict for every call. So if the function mutates it then the default next time will be the mutated value from last time. Making `None` the default and then checking inside the method avoids this problem by allocating a new dict each time the method is invoked.

Comment: Can you [update your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56467744/edit) (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar)? Comments may disappear at any time.

Comment: How about `opts = opts or {}`

Comment: One issue with this -- If *opts* is a mutable parameter that callers will want to see modified values in, it will fail when `{}` is passed in. Probably safer to stick with the traditional two-liner `if opts is None: opts = {}`. If you need a one-liner, I'd prefer `opts = {} if opts is None else opts`.

Comment: @GavinS.Yancey This is true when your function is mutating, but unnecessary otherwise. Given `opts or `if/then/none` is a particularly disorganized construct, and I prefer explicit, functional behavior over mutation, I find `value or default` clearer 9/10 times.