# How can I combine 'name:' and an initialization in a python function?

Tags: python, function, types, initialization, arguments

How can I combine the following:

```
def function(arg1, arg2: str):...
```

and

```
def function(arg1, arg2={}):...
```

?

In the first case, I NEED to enter two arguments. But it can be possible, that `arg2` is not given to the function (-> error). I would like to have the second option but additionally with `: str`, so that I HAVE to give a string as `arg2` to the function IF I like to use `arg2`.

I tried something like

```
def function(arg1, arg2={}: str):...
```

but it did not work. Of course, there is the possibility to check the type inside of the function, that is clear and throw an exception. That is clear. To have a compact solution as with `arg: <type>` in the function call is elegant.

Comment: This question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38727520/adding-default-parameter-value-with-type-hint-in-python).

Comment: Why is the default parameter a dictionary if its supposed to be a string?

Comment: If you need something like this, then I guess you should rethink what you want to do with your function

Comment: Using `arg2={}` is not a good idea. See [“Least Astonishment” and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/3929826) for details!

Comment: "... with ": str", so that I HAVE to give a string ..." Type hints in Python are not enforced by the language runtime, mostly just a friendly reminder to programmers and tools like IDEs about what types should be passed