# Define type of optional function argument

Tags: python, syntax

In Python3 I can do :

```
# Function with string as input
def function(argument: str):
    return argument
```

But I cannot:

```
# Function with optional input
def function(argument='default': str):
    return argument
```

What would be the correct syntax to define the type of an optional argument?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding default parameter value with type hint in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38727520/adding-default-parameter-value-with-type-hint-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Just swap the position of the default value and the type

```
# Function with optional input
def function(argument: str = "default"):
    return argument
```

/EDIT If you really want to express an optional value and not just a default value you could use something like this

```py
from typing import Optional

# Function with optional input
def function(argument: Optional[str] = None):
    return argument
```

Comment: You actually managed to answer my follow up question as well. Thanks for the quick answer :)