# Can I define both function's argument's default value and data type in python?

Tags: python, function, arguments, type-hinting, optional-arguments

I want to write something like this.

1) def func_name(arg1, arg2, arg3 = 3) #this defines default value for optional argument arg3

2) def func_name(arg1, arg2, arg3: int) #and this defines data type for required argument arg3

Is there any possible method to define both of them?
Something like this

def func_name(arg1, arg2, arg3 = 3: int)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding default parameter value with type hint in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38727520/adding-default-parameter-value-with-type-hint-in-python)

Answer (score 22):

You can use like this.

```
def boo(arg1, arg2, arg3: int = 10):
    ....
```

You can find more information [PEP 484's section on default argument values](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#arbitrary-argument-lists-and-default-argument-values)